# Setting irq_handler in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, interrupt-handling, arm7

I am new to ARM and learning about interrupt handling in ARM. I have read about how to set up IRQ handler in ARM but not sure how I write it in ARM assembly. Below is my understanding on setting up IRQ handler.

_IRQ_HANDER:

1) `SUB     lr, lr, #4` (Not sure what it do).

2) Would set up separate stack should be used in IRQ Mode. I know in x86 we set up stack like below:

```
push ebp
mov esp,ebp
sub esp,8
```

This will resrve 8 bytes of stack space.

But not sure how I do the same in ARM?

3) Store the non-banked register, we can do it this way:

```
  STMFD !sp {r13,r14}
```

4) Copy the `CPSR` to `SPSR` (how can I do it ARM assembly?)

5) Move to Processors IRQ mode (I am ok doing this in ARM assembly).

6) What is Next step?

Do we need to give the base address of PIC?

I am working with ARMV7 architecture.

Comment: You really should tell us which ARM architecture you are using. They don't all work the same way.

Comment: @JoeHass,I am with ARMV7 architecture.

Comment: That doesn't sound like ARMv7. More like ARM7.

Comment: @SimonRichter Is interrupt handling on ARM7 is different from ARMv7?

Comment: Absolutely. These are completely different architectures. The "ARM7" core is using the "ARMv4" architecture. Please, take a look at the [table of ARM architectures and cores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Cores).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The program counter on ARM points to the instruction being fetched, rather than the current instruction.

   For normal subroutine calls, this is perfect -- when the program counter is copied to the link register, it already points at the next instruction. In an interrupt handler, it points at the instruction *after* the interrupted instruction, so this needs to be corrected for.

   You can also apply this correction on the way out, e.g. by returning with `SUBS pc, lr, #4`. Note that if the interrupted code was running in Thumb mode, the `lr` is only two bytes ahead, so if you want to support user code in Thumb mode, you need to look at the `spsr_IRQ` to find out which offset to apply.
2. On ARM, you already have a separate stack, because of register banking. When entering IQ mode, the registers `r13` aka `sp` and `r14` aka `lr` are switched over to `r13_IRQ` and `r14_IRQ`, which is why you do not need to restore `lr` for the interrupted application when exiting your interrupt handler.

   This stack needs to be set up before the first interrupt occurs. The kernel startup code at some point switches from the initial `SVC` mode to `IRQ` mode by changing the status register, at which point the `r13_IRQ` register becomes visible, writes the initial stack pointer there and switches back to `SVC` mode.

   Extending the stack frame works basically the same way as on x86, by subtracting from the stack pointer, e.g. using `SUB sp,sp,#8`.

   The x86 code you pasted does more than just extend stack space: it also builds a base pointer chain, which is useful if you want a debugger to display the call stack. For that to work, you need to fill out a full stack frame according to the ABI, with the saved return address in a specific slot etc, which I'd consider an advanced topic. If you expect to use a debugger inside C functions called from your interrupt handler, you can call the first C function with `r12` set to zero, which will make the base pointer chain terminate at your handler function rather than confuse the debugger.
3. You have it backwards -- these two registers are banked and do not need to be saved, unless you are reenabling interrupts while still in the handler. You need to save any registers your handler uses, and restore them prior to returning, the STore Multiple Full Descending (STMFD) instruction is correct for that.
4. This is also backwards. You want to save the `spsr_IRQ` register rather than overwrite it. Again, this is a banked register, so you only need to do this if you are expecting more interrupts before your handler returns (i.e. you clear the "interrupt disable" bit in the PSR).
5. You are already in `IRQ` mode. You leave IRQ mode either by setting a new mode in the status register, or by using an instruction with an `S` suffix (`MOVS`, `SUBS`, `ADDS`, ...) to set the `pc` from the `lr` (the "set status register" bit in this context means "copy the SPSR to the PSR").
6. Afterwards, you handle the reason for the IRQ, typically by asking the interrupt controller (which is outside of the ARM core, so it is model dependent) what occured and then branching off into the appropriate code path. Depending on timing constraints, you can either handle the entire event, or just make a quick note to the idle loop that an interrupt occured and the appropriate function should be called the next time the system is idle.

Returning from an IRQ, you need to clean up the IRQ stack, restore any non-banked registers, and then use `MOVS`, `SUBS` or a similar instruction to set the `pc` and the `cpsr` at the same time.

Comment: Simon thanks for the Detailed answer but to be honest I am still not able  to follow the first point about sub lr,lr #4 ,may be I am asking for too much but is it possible for some kind of diagram description fo this particular point?

Comment: The `pc` register is actually the address for the next instruction fetch, so it is the address of the next, rather than the current instruction. When an interrupt occurs, this value is copied to the `lr`, so if you were to jump to this address, you'd skip one instruction, so you subtract 4 to avoid this.

Comment: when you say the address of next instruction,do you mean first instruction of interrupt handler?I understand  that for normal fucntion call ,we don't subtract 4 from lr and simply store lr value to stack but why in case of interrupt we have to subract value 4.I guess it is as imple thing but I am really having trouble to understand this.

Comment: The instruction that had been "next", before the interrupt. Basically, the interrupt copies `psr` -> `spsr_IRQ`, switches to IRQ mode and replaces the current instruction with a `blx 0x18`, which means that the original instruction is never executed. So yes, that is an implementation issue.

Comment: (also, unless you invoke subroutines, there is no need to push `lr` to the stack)

Comment: Simon ,what I understood is say cpu is executing an instruction add r1 r2,#5 and whenever an interrupt comes ,it stop executing this instruction and move to interrupt handler but cpu has to get back to the interrupted instruction(add r1,r2,#5) and for that 4 is subtracted .also it is not required in case normal routine call where cpu won't come back to called function but to next instruction after called routine,right?

Comment: Exactly. In a normal subroutine call, if you subtracted 4, you'd go back to the branch instruction.

Comment: Thank you very much Simon .It may be annoying for you to answer my every question but you did great help to me.

Comment: Simon to your 2nd point,what I Understtod is whenever an interrupts comes processor moved to irq mode ,so the first instruction executed afer interrupt comes is moving to irq mode not the branch to address 0x18,right?

Comment: That happens without an instruction, because a) it can be trivially implemented and b) it switches to one of the supervisor modes, which you cannot do with an instruction from user mode.